# Emulator not working android

Tags: java, android

I get this message in console Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched.

I tried the thing : "After the emulator is launched right click on the project and launch as android application" and now i get this:

```
Installing name.apk...
Success!
Starting activity com.andrewxd.alphaplatformer.MainActivity on device emulator-5554"
```

But still nothing happens on the emulator.. just the "ANDROID" text flashing on there.

Comment: My guess is you're running Windows.  The ARM emulator starts _very_ slowly.  Go away for half an hour and see if it's up when you come back.

Comment: i'll try to wait 15-20 minutes first and then i will post again

Comment: i installed HAXM and now im fine thanks

Answer (score 1):

It can take a while (about 10 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

> If you are using windows version then you can install Intel x86
> Emulator Accelerator(HAXM)  from "Android SDK Manager" > Extra > Intel
> x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM).
>
> After installing HAXM you need to create emulator using below config.

[image: Emulator Config.]

**Note:**

1. Use CPU emulator Intel Atom (x86)
2. If you give RAM size greater than 512 MB Emulator gives Black screen only.
3. If you want to take an advantage of HAXM to speed up your emulator you need to select "Use Host GPU".
4. Use can select any Taget/ Device which has Intel Atom CPU/ABI.

This HAXM will works fine in onlyk windows machine. Else you have to give RAM size more and disable Host GPU feature.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me all the time when I used ARM... Have you tried to use the Intel emulator? It's way faster! http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture